# Hifi soundstage decentered

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I have spent hours trying to workout why the soundstage, the center of the sound between my speakers, is decentered to one side, in other words the drums vocals bass are normally in the center of the soundstage. In my system they are 60 - 70 % to one side. The set-up. Basically my turntable goes to a phono preamp which has a balance / volume control. This goes to two stereo amps. The one supplies my bass speaker in its own cabinet, the other supplies my mid/high speaker in its own cabinet. In order to provide each amp from the phono preamp, at its output each channel has a rca dual splitter connector. 
Strangely when only one stereo amp is on, the sound is centered. I will gladly supply more details or clarify things.

Answer (score 3):

To me this sounds like one or more of the speakers are "out of phase" meaning you might need to reverse (swap + / -, red / black) connections to the speakers.

Start by doing a simple sanity check: use headphones (can be any model, even a cheap one will do) and check the headphone outputs of each amplifier (assuming they have any). The sound should well centered. A mono signal (old record, an FM mono or AM signal from a radio tuner) should be dead center.

If that's OK then test per amplifier with the speakers, again sound should be dead-center. If it is not then swap the connections on **one** speaker and listen again.

If the combination of mid/high and bass is still not OK then try swapping **both Left and right** connections to the bass speakers **or** the mid/low speakers.

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie for your comment. Strangely during my many trials, I did switch polarity, and it worked for one set of speakers, but not the other! The fact that will only one amp working the sound is centered, but not when both are working, means that Wiebels suggestion (below) could be the answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your preamp is not up to the task of driving both amps in parallel that could cause an issue as described. Your rca splitter cable is a far from optimal salution, as you expose the Output from your preamp with the load of both amps. Normaly I would say in impendancies are so far of that it shouldn't be a problem, but as you state just that I'd go in that direction. If one of you amps has a monitor out (for tapes) try to chain it up. So connest the input of one amp with the monitor/tape output of the other amp.

Comment: Thank you kindly for taking the time to advise me. I cant tell you how I've tried to work it out. Your suggestion that I supply one of the amps with one set of leads, then take a new link out of that amp to input the other amp is an excellent one and I will try it tonight. Thank you.